# How to show a Fragment managed by FragmentPagerAdapter?

Tags: android, fragment

I have a class derived from FragmentPagerAdapter and user swiping works fine (4 tabs), but I would like to show a page/tab/fragment from code. For example, when user taps a textview, I would like to switch to a specific fragment.

I've tried the following without success:

```
public void onClockClick(View v)
{
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm != null) {
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .show(mainFragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know the position of the fragment you want to show then you can simply do: `pager.setCurrentItem(pos)` 
This will automatically animate to the fragment at the desired position. Simple.

If you want to add another fragment to the existing `FragmentPagerAdapter`, then you'll need to first add the fragment's instance to that adapter and then call `notifiyDataSetChanged` on it.